# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Clas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting an error in Rails 3.2 with devise - my view is saying undefined method on line 1 below (user). This view is an edit profile page for logged in users.

So far I've tried changing this to current_user and defining that in my controller which I've provided below, but that did not work.

My only other suspicion is that form_for is not appropriate to use on this page?

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
```

My controller... (as I said I tried current_user)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def find
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :firstname, :dateofbirth, :lastname, :gender, :location, :email, :password)
    end


end
```

Comment: Double check that `@user` is not nil:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630018/undefined-method-model-name?rq=1

Comment: You have to add somehow `@user` in your `edit` action, either add id directly to method or use some filter as you have private `set_user` method, i.e. `before_filter :set_user, only: :edit` ir something similar.

Comment: @zrl3dx I added before_filter and I get a new error: 'Couldn't find User without an ID' conflicting iwth the set_user method in private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise comes with a `current_user` helper method.  You probably don't want to override that, so I'd recommend removing that method from your controller.  In one of my apps I allow users to edit their info and this is my `edit` method:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end
```